# PHP Search through array A for matching id from array B Then print data from array B

Tags: php

Here's what the first array outputs:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 67 [title] => avatar delete any ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 66 [title] => avatar edit any ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 65 [title] => avatar upload ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 8 [title] => comments edit own ) 
[4] => Array ( [id] => 6 [title] => comments post ) 
[5] => Array ( [id] => 9 [title] => comments remove own ) 
[6] => Array ( [id] => 7 [title] => comments vote ) 
[7] => Array ( [id] => 5 [title] => get other members emails )
[8] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => send greetings ) 
[9] => Array ( [id] => 4 [title] => send messages ) 
[10] => Array ( [id] => 64 [title] => use flip chat ) 
[11] => Array ( [id] => 11 [title] => videos add ) 
[12] => Array ( [id] => 13 [title] => videos approve ) 
[13] => Array ( [id] => 12 [title] => videos delete ) 
[14] => Array ( [id] => 14 [title] => videos edit ) 
[15] => Array ( [id] => 10 [title] => videos view ) 
[16] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => view profiles ) 
[17] => Array ( [id] => 3 [title] => vote ) )
```

The Second array outputs this:

```
Array (
[2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => view profiles [AllowedCount] => 5 [AllowedPeriodLen] => 5 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 3 [title] => vote [AllowedCount] => 0 [AllowedPeriodLen] => 0 ) )
```

I'm  using a foreach to loop through the first array to display actions that are enabled.  How would I check if the Key of the second array matches the key of the First, then give variables values from AllowedCount, and AllowedPeriodLen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd reconsider my array design
if the id is really a unique number then redesign the first array to be like that:

```
$arr1 = Array ( 
[67] => avatar delete any
[66] => avatar edit any  
... 
)
```

the second one like that

```
$arr2 = Array (
[2] => Array ( [title] => view profiles [AllowedCount] => 5 [AllowedPeriodLen] => 5 ) 
[3] => Array ( [title] => vote [AllowedCount] => 0 [AllowedPeriodLen] => 0 ) )
```

so that the line matches the id's

then just do something like

```
foreach($arr2 as $key=>$element){
    echo $arr1[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked.  The array_key_exists function came in handy.

```
$bEnabled = array_key_exists($arr1['id'], $arr2);
if($bEnabled){
    $iNumAllowed = $arr2[$arr1['id']]['AllowedCount'];
}
```

Comment: well it makes not real sense to me because first of all i'd rather loop the smaller array. also it makes more sense to loop over arr2 and do something like foreach($arr2 as $permission){$iNumAllowed = $arr2['AllowedCount']};} why looping over 1 if you don't need any vlaue from that? btw is it possible to have some id's in arr2 that are not in arr1? if not then you realy don't need to check if any id from arr2 is in arr1

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't give you all the code to make a proper assessment.  All of this is already going on inside a foreach loop on arr1.